# Как на яндекс карте показать районы города?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть задача показать административные районы города на яндекс картах. 
При этом каждый район должен иметь свой цвет и прозрачность.
Например, здесь отображается один район города:
[на Яндекс Карте](https://maps.yandex.ru/?text=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE&sll=76.943776%2C43.295904&sspn=0.326843%2C0.137171&ol=geo&ouri=ymapsbm1%3A%2F%2Fgeo%3Fll%3D37.401680%252C55.645918%26spn%3D0.066916%252C0.053543%26text%3D%25D0%25A0%25D0%25BE%25D1%2581%25D1%2581%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F%252C%2520%25D0%259C%25D0%25BE%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0%252C%2520%25D0%2597%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BF%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D0%25BD%25D1%258B%25D0%25B9%2520%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BD%25D1%258B%25D0%25B9%2520%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BA%25D1%2580%25D1%2583%25D0%25B3%252C%2520%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B9%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BD%2520%25D0%25A1%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BD%25D1%2586%25D0%25B5%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BE&ll=37.394825%2C55.666104&z=13)

Нужно показать все( или несколько) районы(ов) города и иметь возможность задать им цвет и прозрачность через API.
Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

UPD1. Есть идея сделать районы в виде полигонов. Тогда можно будет править их как угодно. Но нужны координаты границ районов. Карта яндекса откуда же берет эти данные. Вот как их получить?

UPD2. Получен официальный ответ от тех поддержки Яндекс Карт.
"Средствами АПИ Яндекс карт сделать это нельзя". Так что испольуем OSM.

Comment: День добрый tutankhamun. Можно для чайничка выложить готовый код для любого муниципального района любого субъекта. А то не совсем понимаю что не так. Ваш скрипт вставляю и не работает. А без работающего примера не разберусь.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Общий план действий такой:

```
ymaps.ready(function() {
// 0. Создаем карту, например так:
    var map,
        regionName = "Краснодар, Западный округ",
        center = [38.943216, 45.033266],
        zoom = 11;

    map = new ymaps.Map('yamap', {
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom,
        controls: []
    });
// 1. Запрашиваем через геокодер район (у Яндекса этой возможности пока нет, придется пользоваться OSM)
    var url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search";
    $.getJSON(url, {q: regionName, format: "json", polygon_geojson: 1})
        .then(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(ix, place) {
                if ("relation" == place.osm_type) {
// 2. Создаем полигон с нужными координатами
                    var p = new ymaps.Polygon(place.geojson.coordinates);
// 3. Добавляем полигон на карту
                    map.geoObjects.add(p);
                }
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

Этап 1, в качестве примера, приведен с использованием jQuery.

Этап 2 скрывает небольшую проблему. OSM возвращает координаты в порядке (долгота, широта), Яндекс работает по-умолчанию с порядком (широта, долгота). Чтобы это поменять нужно [указать порядок](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/load-docpage/#coordorder) при подключении API

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Также на этапе 2 можно добавить "по вкусу" цвет фона, обводку, прозрачность и многое другое см. [Polygon](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Polygon-docpage/)

Comment: Где ты был раньше Человек!
Столько ручной работы было проделано чтобы получить эти координаты. Загрузка данных с сайта http://beryllium.gis-lab.info/project/osmshp/ shape файлов.
Открытие их в ГИС программе. Поиск пути конвертации данных в GeoJSON.
Наконец, конвертация.
Выдрать из этого огромного файла мне нужные районы.
Вручную выдергивать и добавлять по району.

А оказывается нужно отправить один запрос на АПИ!

tutankhamun ты меня очень сильно помог. Так как мне нужно позже добавлять районы в других городах.

Comment: @AlmaZ Я просто сразу не подумал что можно брать регионы из OSM (а у Яндекса их нету). Бывает вот так :) Как говорят, чтобы дать ответ нужно знать половину ответа. Вы мне эту половину дали в другом вопросе