# Как получить координаты административных районов города в Open Street Map?

Tags: веб-программирование, yandex-maps-api, google-maps, карты, openstreetmap

Нужно показать административные районы городе на карте Яндекса. Уже связался с техподдержкой Яндекса. Их ответ:

> нельзя это сделать средствами апи Яндекс карт

Есть другой путь — нарисовать полигон на карте, но нужно знать координаты границ полигона. Например в виде массива

```
[43.238536, 76.809829],  
[43.229531, 76.814636],  
[43.225028, 76.821674],  
[43.214770, 76.827854],  
[43.209641, 76.833519],
```

и т.д.

Google подсказывает, что эти координаты можно взять в Open Street Map.
Вот только как это сделать?

UPD: ответ на [Как на яндекс карте показать районы города?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462506/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Большое спасибо [tutankhamun](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177613/tutankhamun)

Comment: что это  такое вообще административные районы ?

Comment: Вот теперь сложился паззл. Я ответил на ваш предыдущий вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462506/

Comment: Что такое админ районы?
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RU:Key:boundary