# Яндекс Карты - подсветка регионов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Пишу vba-макрос с отображением карты.

```
    YMaps.jQuery(function () {
        var map = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]);
        map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.617671,55.752283), 6);
        YMaps.Regions.load("ru", function (state, response) {
            if (state == YMaps.State.SUCCESS) {
                var regionVba = response.filter(function (obj) {
                    return obj.name == "Московская область";
                })[0];
                regionVba.setStyle({
                    polygonStyle : {
                        fillColor : "b00c0c55",
                        strokeColor : "b00c0c"
                    },
                    hasHint : true
                });
                map.addOverlay(regionVba);
            } else {
                alert("Error: " + response.error.message)
            }
        });
    })
```

Что нужно изменить в коде, чтобы область подсвечивалась всегда, а не только при наведении?

Примеры взял [отсюда.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/mod/concepts/regions-docpage/)

Comment: А при чем тут VBA?

Comment: Насколько я вижу вы хотите использовать версию 1 Яндекс.Карт. Рекомендую сразу заниматься версией 2.1. Там все более логично устроено и побыстрее на современных браузерах работает.

Comment: @tutankhamun vba генерирует код html и открывает карту в компоненте MS WebBrowser на листе excel, a WebBrowser в Excel - это IE. В 2.1 не нашел подсветки территорий. Я JS не изучал, поэтому экспериментирую на примерах)

Comment: Я недавно на подобный вопрос [отвечал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462531/177613) Если будет что-то непонятно, переформулируйте ваш текущий вопрос

Comment: Кстати в приведенном в ответе коде нужно подключить библиотеку jQuery. Если текущий вопрос будет неактуален, удалите его.

Comment: @tutankhamun переформулирую - в моем примере область подкрашивается в указанный цвет только при наведении на нее мышкой, а мне бы хотелось, чтобы область была всегда подкрашена, без наведении мышки на нее. К сожалению, js абсолютно не владею, поэтому с такой задачей возникли трудности. Конкретно использую [этот пример](https://yandex.github.io/mapsapi-examples-old/html/regions-filterregions.html), смог лишь поменять цвет, с остальным не хватило знаний / не понимание использования API

Comment: Вы приципиально хотите остаться на первой версии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если очень хочется остаться со старым кодом, то можно сделать так:

```
...
if (state == YMaps.State.SUCCESS) {
    var regionVba = response.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.name == "Московская область";
    })[0];
    // Отличия начинаются тут
    // Берем фигуры регионов
    var shapes = regionVba.metaDataProperty.encodedShapes;
    var polygon;
    // Перебираем фигуры
    for (var ix = shapes.length; ix--; ) {
        // Создаем полигон
        polygon = YMaps.Polygon.fromEncodedPoints(
            shapes[ix].coords, 
            shapes[ix].levels
        );
        // Указываем цвета
        polygon.setStyle({
            polygonStyle: {
                fillColor: "b00c0c55",
                strokeColor: "b00c0c"
            }
        });
        // Помещаем полученный полигон на карту
        map.addOverlay(polygon);
    }
} else {
...
```

Минус данного решения по сравнению с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462531/177613) в очень низкой точности отрисовки регионов, однако при этом отрисовка происходит достаточно быстро.

См. также [Region.encodedShapes](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/ref/reference/regions.regionhotspot-docpage/#metaDataProperty), [Polygon.fromEncodedPoints()](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/ref/reference/polygon-docpage/#.fromEncodedPoints)

Comment: спасибо большое - то, что нужно! а на 1-й версии хотчу остаться, потому что тут есть пример с небольшим количеством кода и все в странице html. В 2.1 я открыл песочницу у Яндекса, посмотрел, там кода многовато + файл js отдельно от html, это затруднит мне работу в vba.

Comment: мне как раз не нужна точность и важна скорость отрисовки)