# Как оптимально выделить несколько областей на Яндекс.Картах?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Пишу небольшой макрос с использованием API Яндекс.Карт версии 1.1.
В моём [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474546/%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) мне показали, как можно подсвечивать область постоянно.

А как выделить на карте несколько областей? Конечно можно создавать для каждой области переменную, но что если нужно выделить 20 областей с определёнными названиями?

```
var regionVba = response.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.name == "Московская область";
})[0];
var shapes = regionVba.metaDataProperty.encodedShapes;
var polygon;
for (var ix = shapes.length; ix--; ) {
    polygon = YMaps.Polygon.fromEncodedPoints(
        shapes[ix].coords, 
        shapes[ix].levels
    );
    polygon.setStyle({
        polygonStyle: {
            fillColor: "b00c0c55",
            strokeColor: "b00c0c"
        }
    });
    map.addOverlay(polygon);
}

regionVba1 = response.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.name == "Владимирская область";
})[0];
shapes = regionVba1.metaDataProperty.encodedShapes;
polygon;
for (var ix = shapes.length; ix--; ) {
    polygon = YMaps.Polygon.fromEncodedPoints(
        shapes[ix].coords, 
        shapes[ix].levels
    );
    polygon.setStyle({
        polygonStyle: {
            fillColor: "bccc0c55",
            strokeColor: "bccc0c"
        }
    });
    map.addOverlay(polygon);
}
```

Тогда такой код будет громоздким и неоптимальным. Есть какой-нибудь путь попроще? Например как-нибудь сразу по 20 названиям выделить совокупную область и подсветить её?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно делать два раза одну и ту же работу. Для вашей задачи достаточно исправить фильтр регионов.

```
regionVba = response.filter(function (obj) {
    var names = [
        "Владимирская область",
        "Московская область" // добавить нужный список
    ];
    return (names.indexOf(obj.name) > -1);
});
```

потом формировать полигоны в цикле по элементам массива `regionVba`

PS. Обратите внимание, что метод `Array.indexOf()` не поддерживается в старых браузерах. Придется или изобретать велосипед или воспользоваться готовыми решениями (которых на этом сайте наверняка вагон)

Comment: То, что нужно! Не подскажете, пожалуйста, как в цикле проходить по элементам массив regionVba? С js столкнулся буквально впервые. Я так понимаю, надо в цикле закинуть в shapes по области, но как тут `var shapes = regionVba.metaDataProperty.encodedShapes;` обращаться к определенному элементу массива? С написанием `for (var i in regionVba)` я то справлюсь)

Comment: а, все, разобрался где там индексы, спасибо еще раз!