# Попадает ли точка с заданными координатами в область неточного адреса?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте, имеется необходимость реализовать фильтр  по адресу. При этом, адрес может быть задан неточно. Вроде "Зеленоград" или "Москва, ул. Улицестроителей" или, я не знаю, "Люберцы". Объекты в нашей базе заданы точно (для каждого хранится адрес с точностью до номера квартиры + координаты, определенные с пом. геокодера). Надо понять, какие из наших объектов попадают в адрес, введенный пользователем с строке фильтра.

Поиск по подстроке -- ненадежное решение. По радиусу — тоже. Допустим, ввели в строке поиска "Ленинский проспект" — здесь не радиус нужно задавать, а область в виде очень длинной сосиски...

В общем, может ли Яндекс API определить попадает ли "точный адрес такой-то" в "неточно-заданное пользователем определение такое-то"?

И второй момент: есть ли еще возможность отправить сразу весь массив точных адресов для проверки. А то проверять каждый точный адрес на вхождение в неточный отдельным запросом было бы не очень оптимально..

---

P.S. попытался применить GeoQuery, но, видимо, не умею его готовить..

Вот мой код:

```
gq = ymaps.geoQuery(myMap.geoObjects);

// > GeoQueryResult {_parent: null, _objects: Array[115], _map: null, _cachedBounds: null, _lastPromise: v…}

gq.addToMap(myMap);

// > GeoQueryResult {_parent: null, _objects: Array[115], _map: null, _cachedBounds: null, _lastPromise: v…}

gq_lub = ymaps.geoQuery( ymaps.geocode('Россия, Московская область, Люберцы') );

// > GeoQueryResult {_parent: null, _objects: Array[0], _map: null, _cachedBounds: null, _lastPromise: v…}

gq_lub.addToMap(myMap);

// > GeoQueryResult {_parent: null, _objects: Array[2], _map: null, _cachedBounds: null, _lastPromise: v…}

var result = gq.searchInside(gq_lub);

// > Uncaught TypeError: n is not a function(…)

var result = gq.searchInside( gq_lub.getBounds() );

// > Uncaught Error: geometry.component.pixelContains: Для рассчета вхождения точки геометрия должна быть добавлена на карту.(…)
// ^^ но я же добавлял??
```

Comment: Кстати ошибка проявляется из-за того что `gq_lub.getBounds()` не является геометрией, а только массивом из двух координат. Можно их обернуть в (ymaps.geometry.Rectangle())[https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometry.Rectangle-docpage/] и добавить на карту

Comment: Спасибо. Тут еще одна засада оказалась: похоже, `GeoResult`, полученный из геокодера -- либо точка либо набор точек. Никак не области.. Так что не годится.

Comment: Это не похоже, а точно. Я об этом писал в коммертарии к ответу

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1.** Можно запросить полигон(ы), соответствующий запросу и проверять, попадают ваши объекты в него или нет (искать подходящие объекты можно даже в базе, используя Spatial Extension). Как запросить полигон можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462531/177613)

**Вариант 2.** Скорее идея, чем решение. Можно попробовать собрать дерево областей поиска. То есть если написан адрес *Москва, Графский переулок, дом 14, строение 2*, - переформулировать его в полный адрес, с указанием округов, районов и т. д. и сделать ссылки на родительские области. Например данный объект должен находиться на вот такой ветке иерархии:

```
Москва
    Северо-восточный округ
        Алексеевский район
            Графский переулок
                Дом 14
                    Строение 2
```

При вводе строки поиска делаем поиск области и выдаем все объекты, которые являются потомками найденных областей

Comment: Спасибо, интересные решеия. Однако, мне не дает покоя метод GoeQueryResult.searchInside() -- он выглядит как более простое решение проблемы, но я никак не могу понять как им воспользоваться.

Comment: При этом все равно придется сначала искать область, соответствующую поисковому запросу пользователя, а Яндекс пока этого не умеет (см. ссылку в ответе). Кроме того в соседнем вопросе вы упомянули про `objectManager`, а такие мысли возникают обычно если объектов overДоФига. И мне кажется что `geoQuery()` от такого количества сильно нагрузит браузер. Но это умозрительное заключение. Тестов я не делал

Comment: По второй идее: не то ли это самое, что в `GeocoderMetaData.AddressDetails`?

Comment: Похоже, но надо проверять на реальных данных