# По клику на ссылку города, центрировать и выделять границу города на Яндекс карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть Список городов, как по клику на город центрировать яндекс карту и выделять границу города, как на самой карте [яндекса](http://prntscr.com/c1i05v) реализованно. API 2.1

Comment: Попиарюсь :) Можно сделать также как с районами города в ответе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462531/177613 только в строке запроса оставляете название города

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделение границ - это фишка яндекса и по АПИ они её не распространяют (можете, конечно, сами реализовать). На счет центрирования поможет вот это:
myMap.setCenter([57.767265, 40.925358]);
А чтобы узнать координаты места по его названию, то поможет обратное геокодирование:
[обратное геокодирование](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/reverse_geocode)

Comment: как центрировать уже сделал, а вот с границей города косяк. Но все равно спасибо за ответ!