# Почему некоторые районы на яндекс карте не отображаюся?

Tags: geojson

В продолжении вопроса "[Как на яндекс карте показать районы города?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462506/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/554019#554019)"
Не все регионы отображаются таким образом. К примеру вот не выводится на карте регион:

```
<script>
        ymaps.ready(function() {
// 0. Создаем карту, например так:
    var map,
        regionName = "Bryansk Oblast",
        center = [52.8873315,33.415853],
        zoom = 5;

    map = new ymaps.Map('reviewsmap', {
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom,
        controls: []
    });
// 1. Запрашиваем через геокодер район (у Яндекса этой возможности пока нет, придется пользоваться OSM)
    var url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search";
    $.getJSON(url, {q: regionName, format: "json", polygon_geojson: 1})
        .then(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(ix, place) {
                if ("relation" == place.osm_type) {
// 2. Создаем полигон с нужными координатами
                    var p = new ymaps.Polygon(place.geojson.coordinates);
                    p.options.set('fillColor', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)');
                    p.options.set('strokeColor', '#F8DA19');
// 3. Добавляем полигон на карту
                    map.geoObjects.add(p);
                }
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
</script>
```

И таких примеров могу несколько привести. От чего это зависит непонятно.

Comment: Вы смотрели, какие данные получаете в ответе от поиска openstreetmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я взял для примера области `Volgograd Oblast` и `Bryansk Oblast` и посмотрел данные в ответе от `http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search`.

Для отрисовки области вы отдаете карте массив точек, взятый из `geojson.coordinates`.

У первой области `geojson.type == "Polygon"`, а внутри `geojson.coordinates` один массив. Регион нормально отрисовался на карте.

У "Bryansk Oblast" `geojson.type == "MultiPolygon"`, а внутри `geojson.coordinates` два массива. Регион не отрисовался на карте.

Я не знаком с api openstreetmap, но здесь мы видим, что по поиску могут вернуться как координаты одного региона отрисовки, так и нескольких. А карте нужно отдавать координаты только одного из них (или всех, но по очереди).

Поэтому предлагаю вам правку, которая будет проверять `type` и если он `MultiPolygon` - отрисовывать только первый массив точек:

```
var coordinates = place.geojson.type == "MultiPolygon" ? place.geojson.coordinates[0] : place.geojson.coordinates;
var p = new ymaps.Polygon(coordinates);
```

Еще раз: я не знаком с апи и не знаю, что за второй регион в случае с Брянском. Я отрисовывал их оба на карте и не увидел никакой разницы, поэтому и предлагаю просто рисовать первый. В любом случае, если вы изучите доки api и поймете, что нужно отрисовывать все регионы - это несложно сделать. Теперь вы знаете куда копать.