# Вхождение точки в район города на карте Yandex Map API (JS)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, openstreetmap

У меня вопрос, на который уже дано множество ответов начиная с 2012 года и до наших дней. Решаюсь задать его вновь в 2018, может что-то изменилось)
Итак, задача стоит так:
необходимо программно проверить входит ли точка с координатами [lat, lng] в район города или административный округ.
С использованием YAndex Map API это можно сделать [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462506/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), но есть ряд минусов:

1. Нельзя получить координаты районов города прямо из Яндекс (используем OpenSourceMap - но там данные не 100% актуальные, Центральный район в Красноярске например не находит координаты)
2. Обязательно надо отрисовывать карту. Мне же надо чисто программно определить входит точка в район или нет, карта при этом вообще не нужна. (До сих пор я её просто делал height = 0, чтобы не мешала пользователям.

**Вопрос: есть ли лучшие решения данной задачи, чем это предложено [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462506/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).
Спасибо!**

Comment: нельзя использовать API без показа карты

Comment: Понял спасибо, а карты пока не научились передавать районы городов по API? Ожидается ли этот функционал когда-либо?

Comment: Вообще, может вам подойдет [Геокодер](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/?from=SO) - вы ему точку, он вам город/район/улицу, где она находится.