# Выделение района города в Яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

как можно с помощью API Яндекс карт, выделить район город или муниципальное образование?

Нашел [тут вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462506/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), он задан в 15' году, решение с геокодером OSM.

> // 1. Запрашиваем через геокодер район (у Яндекса этой возможности пока нет, придется пользоваться OSM)

Возможно за это время возможность появилась.
В документации к API [нашел функцию](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geocode.html?lang=ru) `geocode`, однако не до конца понял как ей пользоваться, тем более что она выдает в ответ на запрос ошибку.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  myMap = new ymaps.Map(
    "map", {
      center: [59.853356, 30.033788],
      zoom: 11,
      controls: ["typeSelector"]
    }, {
      typeSelectorSize: "small"
    }
  );

  ymaps
    .geoQuery(
      ymaps.borders.load("RU", {
        lang: "ru",
        quality: 3
      })
    )
    .search('properties.hintContent = "Санкт-Петербург"')
    .setOptions({
      strokeColor: "rgba(218, 24, 24, 1)",
      strokeWidth: "1",
      fillColor: "rgba(218, 24, 24, 0.15)"
    })
    .addToMap(myMap);

  var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode("Moscow");
  myGeocoder.then(
    function(res) {
      res.geoObjects;
      alert("good");

    },
    function(err) {
      alert("bad"); // err == Object{message: "scriptError"}
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Геокодер Яндекс по-прежнему не возвращает координаты вершин полигонов искомых объектов.

Максимум, что сейчас возможно получить через JS API Яндекс.Карт — [границы регионов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/regions.html). Примеры также есть у них в [песочнице](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions_colors).

Более детальные объекты необходимо всё так же получать на сторонних сервисах, например OSM.